# AttributeConverter convertToEntityAttribute loop a record and always get null value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an Auditable class like below:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

public abstract class Auditable<U> {

    @JsonIgnore
    @CreatedBy
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Convert(converter = UserConvert.class)
     protected HiUser createdby;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    protected Date created;

    @JsonIgnore
    @LastModifiedBy
    @Convert(converter = UserConvert.class)
    protected HiUser updatedby;

    @JsonIgnore
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date updated;

    // Getter Setter
}
```

With converter like below:

```
@Converter
public class UserConvert implements AttributeConverter<HiUser, Integer>{

private static final Logger Log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserConvert.class);
@Autowired AppUserRepository repository;

@Override
public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(HiUser attribute) {
    int userId = 1;

    if(null != attribute)
        userId = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(attribute.getHiUserId()));

    return userId;
}

@Override
public HiUser convertToEntityAttribute(Integer dbData) {
    HiUser user;

    Log.info("dbData : {}", dbData);

    try {
        user = repository.findByHiUserId(Long.getLong(String.valueOf(dbData)));
        return user;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        user = null;
    }
    return user;
}
```

}

When I save createdby, it work like what I want, but when I retrieve the data, it return **null**.
What makes me confuse is when I select the data, the auditable execute more than one time like in logs below:

```
2018-08-13 17:43:32.463 TRACE 32753 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [24]
2018-08-13 17:43:32.467  INFO 32753 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] i.co.trial.util.UserConvert  : dbData : 11
2018-08-13 17:43:32.468  INFO 32753 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] i.co.trial.util.UserConvert  : dbData : 11
2018-08-13 17:43:32.468  INFO 32753 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] i.co.trial.util.UserConvert  : dbData : 1
2018-08-13 17:43:32.469  INFO 32753 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] i.co.trial.util.UserConvert  : dbData : 1
2018-08-13 17:43:32.469  INFO 32753 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] i.co.trial.util.UserConvert  : dbData : 1
2018-08-13 17:43:32.469  INFO 32753 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] i.co.trial.util.UserConvert  : dbData : 1
```

Ps : 11 is my user id that insert in field createdby and updatedby.

I am pretty new in Java, any help is appreciated. Thanks

### Update :

This is my HiUser class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="hi_user")
public class HiUser extends Auditable<HiUser> implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6435055512245662354L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(schema = "PUBLIC", name="USER-SEQ",sequenceName="HI_USER_SEQ", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER-SEQ")
    private long hiUserId;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

// Getter Setter
}
```

### Solve :

My tentative conclusion is that i can't do a database query in converter, so i remove the converter and do some changes in class `Auditable` and `AuditorAwareImpl` like below, and everything work again:

**Auditable**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class Auditable<U> {

    @JsonIgnore
    @CreatedBy
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    protected long createdby;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    protected Date created;

    @JsonIgnore
    @LastModifiedBy
    protected long updatedby;

    @JsonIgnore
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date updated;

    // Getter Setter
}
```

**AuditorAwareImpl**

```
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<Long>{

    @Autowired
    AppUserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public Long getCurrentAuditor() throws NullPointerException {

        String Username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();

        HiUser hiUser = repository.findByEmail(Username);
        return hiUser.getHiUserId();
    }

}
```

Comment: Wild guess `HiUser` is also an `Auditable`?

Comment: Hi sir, M.Deinum i have update my question. thanks :)

Comment: The comment was the answer for your loop... The `HiUser` is an audible, which uses a `HiUser`.... Which is again is an `Auditable`, which uses a `HiUser`..... Which is again an `Auditable` etc. etc. etc. until you get a stackoverflow, which makes your method eventually return `null`.

Comment: Still not work, what i found so far is if i have one to one relationship and both of them using `Auditable` then it will trigger converter too, that why i get `dbData : 1` in log. any advice ?

Comment: of course it will. The `Auditable` uses a `HiUser` so yes eventually everything will use the converter. But why on earth do you need the converter if the `HiUser` is an entity already. You are fighting the framework instead of using it. You don't need a converter.

Comment: @M.Deinum : Thanks sir, your hint make it work now. i just realize that i can't query in @converter (if it is true). so i remove the converter and change `createdby` and `updatedby` to `long`, and also change parameter to `Long` in `getCurrentAuditor` method. Thank you so much.